# Making the qed symbol appear at the end of an align only on the last overlay of a frame

Tags: beamer, align, qed

I would like the qed symbol to appear only on the last slide of this frame. Can someone help me?

```
\documentclass[10pt, professionalfonts, aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Propriedades da Adição e da Multiplicação por Número em $\mathbb{R}^n$}
\begin{proof}
(Continuação)
  \begin{enumerate}[(a)]\addtocounter{enumi}{7}
    \item
    \begin{align*}
      \lambda (\boldsymbol{u} + \boldsymbol{v})  &= \lambda \left( (u_1,\, \dots,\, u_n) + (v_1,\, \dots,\, v_n) \right)\\
                                                 \onslide<2->{&= \lambda ( u_1 + v_1,\, \dots,\, u_n + v_n )\\}
                                                 \onslide<3->{&= \left( \lambda (u_1 + v_1),\, \dots,\, \lambda (u_n + v_n) \right)\\}
                                                 \onslide<4->{&= ( \lambda u_1 + \lambda v_1,\, \dots,\, \lambda u_n + \lambda v_n )\\}
                                                 \onslide<5->{&= (\lambda u_1,\, \dots,\, \lambda u_n) + (\lambda v_1,\, \dots,\, \lambda v_n)\\}
                                                 \onslide<6->{&= \lambda (u_1,\, \dots,\, u_n) + \lambda (v_1,\, \dots,\, v_n)\\}
                                                 \onslide<7->{&= \lambda \boldsymbol{u} + \lambda \boldsymbol{v}. \qedhere} 
    \end{align*}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{proof}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I just found a solution: inserted ```\only<1-6>{\let\qed\relax}``` at the beginning of the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the `qed symbol` template to make it only visible on the 7th overlay:

```
\documentclass[10pt, professionalfonts, aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{
%amssymb,
latexsym}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Propriedades da Adição e da Multiplicação por Número em $\mathbb{R}^n$}
\setbeamertemplate{qed symbol}{\visible<7->{\openbox}}
\begin{proof}
(Continuação)
  \begin{enumerate}[(a)]\addtocounter{enumi}{7}
    \item
    \begin{align*}
      \lambda (\boldsymbol{u} + \boldsymbol{v})  &= \lambda \left( (u_1,\, \dots,\, u_n) + (v_1,\, \dots,\, v_n) \right)\\
       \onslide<2->{&= \lambda ( u_1 + v_1,\, \dots,\, u_n + v_n )\\}
       \onslide<3->{&= \left( \lambda (u_1 + v_1),\, \dots,\, \lambda (u_n + v_n) \right)\\}
       \onslide<4->{&= ( \lambda u_1 + \lambda v_1,\, \dots,\, \lambda u_n + \lambda v_n )\\}
       \onslide<5->{&= (\lambda u_1,\, \dots,\, \lambda u_n) + (\lambda v_1,\, \dots,\, \lambda v_n)\\}
       \onslide<6->{&= \lambda (u_1,\, \dots,\, u_n) + \lambda (v_1,\, \dots,\, v_n)\\}
       \onslide<7->{&= \lambda \boldsymbol{u} + \lambda \boldsymbol{v}. \qedhere} 
    \end{align*}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{proof}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Unrelated:

- you don't need to load the `amssymb` and `amsmath`, beamer loads them automatically
- if your tex distribution is reasonable new, you don't need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, that's the default since a couple of years
- I wouldn't do `\usepackage{enumerate}` with beamer. Beamer automatically loads the `enumerate` package and then makes some adjustments to it afterwards.